# Filter for Outlook contact where CompanyName = "..."

Tags: vba, outlook, contacts

I started to write a code, but I don't know what I need to write in the variable objContact to select an item contact in the folder.

I tried:

```vb
sFilter = "[CompanyName= 'BEIS'"
Set objContact = objContactsFolder.Items.Find(sFilter)
objContact.Delete
```

Currently my code looks like that:

```vb
Sub ChangeCompanyName()

     Dim objContactsFolder 'As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim objContacts 'As Outlook.Items
     Dim strCo 'As String
     Dim objContact 'As Object
     Dim iCount 'As Integer

   ' Set

     Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set objNameS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set objContactsFolder = objNameS.GetDefaultFolder(olContactItem)
     Set objContacts = objContactsFolder.Items

   ' Delete Contact if company names = strCo

     strCo = "BEIS"

     Set objContact = ???

     For Each objContact In objContacts
       If TypeName(objContact) = "ContactItem" Then
         If objContact.CompanyName = strCo Then
            objContact.Delete
         End If
       End If
     Next

   ' Clean up

     Set objContact = Nothing
     Set objContacts = Nothing
     Set objContactsFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem? As you step through the code, which line of your code fails or behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what I need to write in objContact to select an item contact in the folder, i'have tried this :                       `sFilter = "[CompanyName=  'BEIS'"  Set objContact = objContactsFolder.Items.Find(sFilter) objContact.Delete`  But nothing happens :( .

Comment: So have you tried to put a breakpoint and step through your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is wrong. You are missing "]":

```
sFilter = "[CompanyName] = 'BEIS'"
```

Comment: I edit my script with Notepad++ and I think it haven't "breakpoint".           I added "]" but it's same result nothing happens. I found an alternative !   I don't know why but in Excel/Outlok VBA my script is working, so I'm going to use this command for run the macro :                                    `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\Deleter.xls") 
 
   objExcel.Run "'Deleter.xls'!Deleter" 
 
   wb.Close 
   objExcel.Quit
   oShell.Run "taskkill /im EXCEL.exe", , True`

Comment: But you don't run you code from Notepad++, right? And when running from VBA in either Office app, you can set breakpoints.

Comment: Now I'm running a part of my script in VBA ( the part for delete contacts and the script is working)and the other part in VBS .                             
That looks like that in my VBS: `Run Macro "Deleter" from excel to delete the old contacts who have CompanyName = "BEIS", when that is finishing; run the VBS commands for add the new contacts `. So that means I needn't have the breakpoints.